# Rationals with subspace topology from the reals

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\mathbb{Q}$ is endowed with the subspace topology of$\mathbb{R}$ Does it follow that $\mathbb{Q}$ is connected?

MY attempt: We can sue fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and so $\mathbb{Q} = \bigcup \{x\} $. And singletons are connected. Can we conclude that the union is connected?

Comment: No.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the relative topology, $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally
 disconnected.

Comment: some might say *totally* disconnected.

Comment: Yerright. I meant "totally" in the sense that each point is a connected component.

Answer (score 1):

Why would the union of two connected sets be connected? Think about why this is not true in general. The rationals are certainly not connected.

Comment: Nor is a finite set with more than two elements.

Comment: Not necessarily. The indiscreet topology on the set of 2 points is certainly connected.

Comment: Not as as subset of the line; that is the context I am responding to.

Comment: Ah. I apologise.

Comment: no worries here.

Comment: @bof Autocorrect... Thanks.